# How to convert hex(base16) value of hash SHA-256 to Unsigned Integer(7) (base10) in Scala?

Tags: scala, long-integer, sha256, unsigned-integer

Logic which is working in Abinitio platform.
Lets take sample value as “123456789”, for which we need to generate SHA256 and convert into unsigned integer(7).  Expected result  - *40876285344408085*

`m_eval 'hash_SHA256("123456789")'`
*[void 0x15 0xe2 0xb0 0xd3 0xc3 0x38 0x91 0xeb 0xb0 0xf1 0xef 0x60 0x9e 0xc4 0x19 0x42 0x0c 0x20 0xe3 0x20 0xce 0x94 0xc6 0x5f 0xbc 0x8c 0x33 0x12 0x44 0x8e 0xb2 0x25]*

`m_eval 'string_to_hex(hash_SHA256("123456789"))'`
*"15E2B0D3C33891EBB0F1EF609EC419420C20E320CE94C65FBC8C3312448EB225"*

`m_eval '(unsigned integer(7)) reinterpret(hash_SHA256("123456789"))'`

*40876285344408085*

**Scala Approach**

```
println("Input Value : "+shaVal)

val shaCode="SHA-256"
val utf="UTF-8"

val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(shaCode)
  println("digest SHA-256 : "+digest)

val InpStr = StringUtils.stripStart(shaVal,"0")
  println("InpStr : "+InpStr)

val hashUTF = digest.digest(InpStr.getBytes(utf))
  println("hashUTF(UTF-8) : "+hashUTF.mkString(" "))

val hashBigInt= new BigInteger(1, digest.digest(InpStr.getBytes("UTF-8")))
  println("hashBigInt : "+hashBigInt)

val HashKeyRes = String.format("%032x", hashBigInt)
  println("HashKeyRes : "+HashKeyRes)
```

**Console Output**

```
hashUTF(UTF-16) : 21 -30 -80 -45 -61 56 -111 -21 -80 -15 -17 96 -98 -60 25 66 12 32 -29 32 -50 -108 -58 95 -68 -116 51 18 68 -114 -78 37
hashBigInt : 9899097673353459346982371669967256498000649460813128595014811958380719944229
HashKeyRes : 15e2b0d3c33891ebb0f1ef609ec419420c20e320ce94c65fbc8c3312448eb225
fromBase : 16
toBase : 10
```

So the hash key generated matches with the value, which is HEX format (Base16). But the  expected output should be in(Base10) Unsigned Integer (7)  as **40876285344408085**

Comment: I have a suspicion that your expectations are incorrect. Specifically, if you convert a 32-digits hex number into decimal _properly_, there's no way it'll end up as a 17-digit decimal. So, there seems to be some truncation happening in the `(unsigned integer(7)) reinterpret(hash_SHA256("123456789"))`, but in scala code you're not truncating anything.

So, either you need to figure out how exactly it is truncated in the "working" version, or maybe your "working" version has an error and should not truncate?

Comment: Input is a 9 digit no. SHA produced array[byte] which has 32 elements.
I have got 3 possible formats available, you can try converting anyone into Unsigned Integer(7)  from any of the below formats.

hashUTF(UTF-16) :Array [bytes] = [ 21 -30 -80 -45 -61 56 -111 -21 -80 -15 -17 96 -98 -60 25 66 12 32 -29 32 -50 -108 -58 95 -68 -116 51 18 68 -114 -78 37 ]
hashBigInt : BigInteger = 9899097673353459346982371669967256498000649460813128595014811958380719944229
HashKeyRes : Hex(Base16)=
15e2b0d3c33891ebb0f1ef609ec419420c20e320ce94c65fbc8c3312448eb225

I was trying to convert from hex to Int

Comment: In Abinitio hash_SHA256("123456789") when casted as unsigned integer(7) has produced result as "40876285344408085"

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve, but you're essentially asking "how could I truncate the 32 hex numbers into 17 decimal numbers the same way abinitio is doing it". There's no obvious error or visible pattern (at least to me :)), so it's unlikely someone (including me) would invest enough time to reverse-engineer abinitio truncation - maybe try asking their support would work better and produce more authoritative answer?

Comment: @J0HN - So you mean any value if converted across different platforms will generate different results.?

Comment: No, I mean that reinterpret cast of 32 digit hex into unsigned integer(7) looses precision. How exactly it loses precision depends on the implementation. Implementation, unless it follows some standard, can (and probably will) vary between platforms. So, I would suggest avoiding something that depends on the implementation and sticking with something you can control - e.g. bit shift, taking N least/most significant bytes, etc. With your current approach the only option is to reverse-engineer the truncation that happens in the  `(unsigned integer(7)) reinterpret(hash_SHA256("123456789"))`